# Code Analysis Error (Unexpected namespace prefix) after upgrading Android Support Library 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I upgraded to Android Support Library 23.2.0 and added

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

to my build.gradle, so that I have vector drawable support for apis lower than 21. (See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) for details).

I also replaced

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
```

with

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
```

in every Imageview that uses vector drawables.

The app compiles and works perfectly fine, but code analysis reports:

> Error:(56, 9) Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag `ImageView`

Why is this the case? Why is it compiling although I am getting errors?

EDIT: I have added

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

in my root layout.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lint, Android's code analysis tool, doesn't seem to know about support vector drawables, yet. You can safely ignore the error by adding `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` to the `ImageView` tag.

Comment: Also add `tools:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"` to preview the drawable in the layout

Comment: It works for me. Please mentioned this line too in your answer xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Answer (score 2):

Change ImageView to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView in your XML

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this error, because original ImageView doesn't have srcCompat attribute. This attribute is used only by AppCompatImageView, which is injected instead of ImageView you declared. This error is easy to spot when using overloaded view inflaters. Lint performs static analysis and doesn't know about hacks you can do with xml from code.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add this to top parent layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` as attribute either to your `ImageView` or to the `Top-Level` Tag like `LinearLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, `RelativeLayout`.. etc

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>
```

or in parent layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>
```

Comment: sync gradle try to run.